# How to check a runtime type in C#

Tags: c#

I'm using the `Type.GetType()` method to return a type given a string; however, I'm struggling to find a way to check the type:

```
var type = Type.GetType("ConsoleApp2.Class1");

if (type is ConsoleApp2.Class1) // Is never true, and gives a warning to that effect
{

}

switch (type)
{
    case ConsoleApp2.Class1: 
        // Will not compile (Expression of Type cannot be handled by a pattern of type Class1
        break;
}
```

I've tried various combinations, but clearly I'm missing something. I realise I could just check the text, but that feels dirty.

Comment: You might want to use `typeof()` like `if (type == typeof(ConsoleApp2.Class1))`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to wrap `ConsoleApp2.Class1` with the [`typeof` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#typeof-operator) to get an object of type `Type`, which can be compared to your other type object.

If you want to check for exact equality, you can use `Type.Equals` or `==`.

```
var type1 = Type.GetType("ConsoleApp2.Class1");
var type2 = typeof(ConsoleApp2.Class1);

if (type1.Equals(type2)) { ... } 
if (type1 == type2) { ... }
```

If you want to check for equality *or a subtype relationship* (similar to `myObject is SomeType`), you can use

```
if (type1.IsAssignableFrom(type2)) { ... }
```